# Function in JOIN condition

Tags: postgresql, index, join, functions

I have big dynamically constructed query with

```
FROM main_table t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON my_func(t.col1, 1) = t1.col1
...
LEFT JOIN table6 t6 ON my_func(t.col1, 6) = t6.col1
```

Query is very slow, but if I remove `my_func()` from `JOIN` condition, it works ok. Next variant has the same time:

```
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , my_func(col1, 1) AS join_cond1
    ...
    , my_func(col1, 6) AS join_cond6
  FROM main_table
) t
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON join_cond1 = t1.col1
  ...
  LEFT JOIN table6 t6 ON join_cond6 = t6.col1
```

How I can speed up the query?

**Update**

I wrote that I can't create 6 indexes on all the `table1...table6`, but indexes are needed on `main_table` only. Sorry for my mistake.

`PostgreSQL` has functional indexes, and I tried dynamic generation like

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ix_main_table_my_func_'||_number||' ON main_table (my_func(col1, '||_number||'))';
```

and it was much more quickly than `CTE`. But I have troubles with deadlock if function is called concurrently from multiple places since `CREATE INDEX` sets lock. `PostgreSQL` can `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ...`, but it does not work in transaction blocks (and functions because functions are executed in transaction blocks).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please show the definition of the function - specifically whether it's marked `immutable` or `stable`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's going to be slow. Best would be to pre-chew the data by adding those JOIN fields as computed columns to MainTable. If you don't control that table, you can try rewriting your query with a CTE, though I'm not sure how much it will help:

```
WITH NewMainTable
AS (
    SELECT t.*
        , my_func(t.col1, 1) as MyJoinField1
        , = my_func(t.col1, 6) as MyJoinField6 
    FROM MainTable t
    )
SELECT *
FROM NewMainTable nmt
    JOIN table1 t1
        ON nmt.MyJoinField1 = t1.col1
    JOIN table6 t6
        ON nmt.MyJoinField6 = t6.col1;
```

Comment: Specifially, PERSISTED computed columns.

Comment: Postgres has neither computed columns, nor persisted computed columns. Turning the derived table into a CTE won't improve the performance either

Comment: My bad, I didn't even see this was postgres - it showed up in my SQL filter. Best bet then is to create actual fields and fill them in your INSERT code (trigger, maybe?).

Comment: Rewriting subquery (as I showed in question) to the CTE gave me an acceleration of 4 times, thanks! Using of temp tables has about the same speed in Postgres, even slightly slower.

Comment: w00t! Glad it helped. And many thanks to @horse for Postgres-ifying the code.

Comment: Updated the question. It seems that indexes is batter way, but I have troubles with them.